# Mark packets with iptables by destination mac address

Tags: networking, iptables, nat, traffic-shaping

I need to mark packets which goes to a specified mac address.

I need this to use in shaper with `tc`.

`--mac-destination` doesn't exist in `iptables`.

Also I tried to use `ebtables`:

`ebtables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 9c:4e:36:aa:bb:cc -j mark --set-mark 0x2003 --mark-target ACCEPT`

but it doesn't mark anything (at least `ebtables -t nat -L --Lc` shows me 0 counters)

Please help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to combine iptables `--mac-source` with `CONNMARK`:

- First use `--mac-source` to match packets coming from the mac address you're interested in. It's the wrong direction since you're interested in packets going to this mac address, but now you can
- use `CONNMARK` to mark the whole connection, ie both directions (!) and
- set the mark from the connection mark with `--restore-mark`

```
# lan interface
if_lan=eth0

# create 'mark_mac' table for marking connections:
iptables -t mangle -N mark_mac
iptables -t mangle -A mark_mac -j MARK --set-mark 1234
iptables -t mangle -A mark_mac -j CONNMARK --save-mark

# mark connections involving mac address:
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i $if_lan -m state --state NEW -m mac --mac-source 9c:4e:36:aa:bb:cc -j mark_mac

# mark packets going to mac:
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -o $if_lan -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
```

Initially i thought this would only work for tcp connections originating from the lan, but given the definition of `--state NEW` it should work in both directions for both tcp and udp (!)

See also [Policy Routing on Linux based on Sender MAC Address](https://linuxmonk.ch/wordpress/index.php/2016/policy-routing-on-linux-based-on-sender-mac-address/) which was the inspiration for this answer.

Comment: `-m state` got deprecated, use `-m conntrack --ctstate NEW` instead (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/690783/544026)

Answer (score -1):

`iptables`works at the OSI layer 3, so it knows nothing whatsoever about MAC addresses.

In fact, it does have a [mac module](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html), which however contains only the further filter `--mac-source`: this is because ethernet packets coming in do carry the MAC address of their source. However, such a MAC address does not exist for packets coming thru wifi, and it is not relevant to outgoing packets. The reference above states:

> Note that this only makes sense for packets coming from an Ethernet device and entering the PREROUTING, FORWARD or INPUT chains.

As for `ebtables`, first of all it can be used only with Ethernet frames, because wifi frames miss one MAC addrees. Second, MAC source addresses, as I said above, do not exist in IP packets.

If you wanted to control ARP packets, you would find out quickly that there is an instruction

> **arp-mac-dst [!] address[/mask]**
>
> The (R)ARP MAC destination address specification

but, once again, this is becausethe ARP protocol **does** use MAC addresses, unlike the IP protocol.

Comment: Thank you. I used `ebtables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p arp --arp-mac-dst bc:5f:f4:aa:bb:cc -j mark --mark-set 0x2003` and `ebtables -t nat -L --Lv` shows no matches..

Comment: This answer is misleading: wifi networks do have mac addresses and `iptables --mac-source` works fine with them. The man page should probably read "... coming from an ethernet/wifi device"